# Simple URL rewriting doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got an URL like this `www.mysite.it/indexa.php?pag=azienda` and an URL like
`www.mysite.it/azienda`.

I've already read the other question and I've wrote in my `.htaccess` this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /([a-z]+)/ http://www.mysite.it/indexa.php?pag=$1 [R]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your rule `/([a-z]+)/` accepts urls like those:

- /a/
- /abc/
- /abcghijk/
- /abc/def

but not these ones:

- /a
- /abc
- /abcghijk

Do you see the pattern? The trailing slash. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/? /indexa.php?pag=$1 [R,QSA]
```

Comment: I've also tried this RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /indexa.php?pag=$1 [R,QSA] but urls still remains the same